# Display or save a log of kernel panic without CONFIG_PRINTK enabled

Tags: linux-kernel, panic

How to display or save a chunk of the log with disabled `CONFIG_PRINTK`?

Comment: dump_stack and all other log utilities need printk.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't. If `CONFIG_PRINTK=N`, then you're out of luck, you won't be able to see a panic logged to the TTY. The kernel also doesn't normally save logs anywhere in case of a panic, as the mere fact that it's panicking means it cannot be relied on, and writing to the filesystem is not a good idea.

Edit: as suggested in the comments you might get away with `CONFIG_PRINTK=n` if you use [this technique](https://elinux.org/Do_Printk) to manually patch the kernel. Of course this requires a re-compilation of the kernel from source though, so not sure how much it helps in your situation.

With that said, just take a look at [the description of `CONFIG_PRINTK`](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/PRINTK.html):

> This option enables normal `printk` support. Removing it eliminates most of the message strings from the kernel image and makes the kernel more or less silent. As this makes it very difficult to diagnose system problems, saying N here is strongly discouraged.

Without `CONFIG_PRINTK`, you will have no logs at all. No verbose boot messages, no warnings, no stack traces, no panic logs. Even [`panic()` uses `printk`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/kernel/panic.c#L225).

If you really need to troubleshoot a situation in which you don't have `printk` enabled, you will need to setup [`kdump`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/kernel_administration_guide/kernel_crash_dump_guide) to save the panicked kernel image to be inspected later (good luck with that).

Comment: I think there's a per module work around / override for CONFIG_PRINTK=n, as described here https://elinux.org/Do_Printk
if kernel is configured  with CONFIG_PRINTK_FUNC=y and CONFIG_PRINTK=n then you could add #define DO_PRINTK and still log some information to _log_buf. and even print it if you wish to.

Comment: Yes, I already tried to enable printk for only panic, but it didn't help.
main problem: kernel having a reboot with printk turned off.
If I turn it on, then everything works. I think that there is a panic, but since there is no printk I can not find the reason.
I have nvram and, in fact, during a panic, I can add a function to save logs from a panic.

Comment: @CallMeRK interesting, didn't know of this technique. Added as an edit, thanks.

Comment: @Snordic hmm, the kernel cannot just reboot with `CONFIG_PRINTK=n`, that's a compilation setting. I assume that it's rebooting either into another kernel or into the same kernel with some command line parameters that disable logging. You will need to give a more detailed explanation of what is going on, or it's impossible to answer.

Comment: @Marco Bonelli Okay, what's the problem, my kernel is not quite vanilla, but when I made the next commit there was a problem:
https://www.spinics.net/lists/systemd-devel/msg05191.html

This problem is observed precisely when CONFIG_PRINTK is disabled. If you turn it on, then there is no reboot.
That's all I can say. I think this is panic.

Comment: I think you can, if kernel Oopses, retrieve data with help of crash dump (kdump) approach.